# what kind of url i should give in order to connect

Tags: docusignapi

Hi iam using docusign connect to auto notify the status. but i am getting a  problem in connection . what kind of url i should give to connect.i am giving the url as follows http:localhost/embedded/index.php. but i am getting error when made connection.error is   Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 0345f0c5-15b8-4548-87e7-762c2a95f042 :: http://localhost/embedded/connect.php :: Error - Unable to connect to the remote server; No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80. please tell me how can i connect and how to read that postdata.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the Connect service guide first: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect. The DocuSign Connect endpoint that you configure must be an internet facing URL since the DocuSign cloud will need to send messages to it. Localhost is not going to work.

NOTE: When testing in DEMO, you can specify an HTTP or HTTPS endpoint, however in PROD the endpoint must be HTTPS. Please keep that in mind as you think about your production steps.